# Getting started with cocoa for os x?

Tags: cocoa, macos, ios

I am familiar with iOS programming, but I don't know where to put my logic when I start a Cocoa project for OS X. Are there any good online resources for transitioning to OS X from iOS?

EDIT:

Thanks for the help so far. My main question is where my code goes in the default template.

Comment: Try the basic walkthroughs for developing an OS X application in Apple's developer resources - the similarities and differences should be clear. I can't think of anything for transitioning in that direction (most transition guides are the other way round).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My main question is where my code goes in the default template.

Assuming a single-window app, I make a separate custom controller to own that window, and I have the application object's delegate own that controller.

So:

#### The application object's delegate

- Owns the custom controller.
- Creates it in `applicationWillFinishLaunching:` (note: not `Did`; I change this).
- Releases it (and `nil`s out the instance variable) in `applicationWillTerminate:`.
- Does not own the primary window (I remove that ivar and all references to it).
- Responds to `applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:` with `YES`, so that the user can quit the application either by specifically quitting or by closing the primary window.
- May also respond to `application:openFile:` or `application:openFiles:`, typically by passing the file(s) along to the controller to import or something.

#### The MainMenu nib

- Owns the application's delegate.
- Does not contain the primary window (I remove the blank one).

#### The primary-window controller

- Owns the primary window.
- Owns the model displayed in the window.
- Creates initial/empty model in `init`.
- Loads the primary-window nib with itself as owner in `init`.
- Closes and releases window (first) and releases model (second) and subordinate controllers (third) in `dealloc`.

#### The primary-window nib

- Named similarly to the controller; e.g., “SnippetListController” for the controller and “SnippetList” for the nib.
- Contains the primary window.
- Primary window has “visible on launch” (really on nib load) turned on and “release when closed” turned off.

The advantage of all of this is that the lifetime of every object but the application's delegate is clear and explicit, as is the area of responsibility. My application's delegate is little more than that; the only thing it does that isn't specifically an app-delegate job is owning the primary-window controller. Likewise, the primary-window controller does nothing but own the primary window and whatever model I have to show in that window. And at quit time, everything but the application's delegate gets deallocked.

For document-based apps, I stick pretty close to the template. I delete any template methods I don't need to customize, and I may switch one or both of the I/O methods to one of the other versions (e.g., from `readFromData:ofType:error:` to `readFromURL:ofType:error:`), and maybe delete the write method if I'm writing a viewer only; that's about it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this when I get back to my iMac on Monday.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had time yet. I will try to get to this soon.

Comment: so basically most of the application's code will be in that 1 window controller? i'm used to cocoa-touch ios apps where there are many controllers.

Comment: @binnyb: I try to put as much as makes sense into the model class(es), which means my one controller gets maybe up to half of the code but is almost never especially long. (My apps are small, which helps.) It's usually not a good idea to base refactorings purely on code size; a bigger problem is keeping all of your code in controllers, regardless of how many they are. If a class gets long, it's time to rethink your design, not simply dynamite that class into several pieces. In the case of a single large controller, my first thought will always be how much of it should be moved to the model.

Comment: thanks for the advice! i have a window controller which manages an xib with 2 nested tabviews - this seems to generate a lot of code with just connecting the outlet views and creating that logic.  i'm just a little unsure of the design of mac apps for when separation is optimal

Answer (score 1):

Dive in.

Seriously just jump in with both feet. Find something that you want to make and just make it.

From what you've said you've already got a fair bit of experience with Objective-C and Cocoa and most things carry straight across.

Comment: He has experience with Cocoa Touch, not Cocoa, but yeah, most concepts seem (at least to me, as someone who doesn't use Cocoa Touch) pretty similar. The big difference is in table views.

Comment: @Peter I'd say the big difference is wrapping your brain around `NSCell` and friends...